Is there a way to make my r codes in my package not accessible to users?
I do not want my clients to see the codes used in functions when they use my r package. Is there a way to do this?

Write them in C or C++, and call them from R.

The short answer is no. There is no way to do this with 100% certainty. You can make it harder for them to inspect the code, but if you're distributing the package for them to run on their computers determined users will eventually be able to inspect it all if they really want to.
